# Ruby on Rails - Improve page with ads and images on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, lazy-loading, pagespeed

My application is a gallery-based application. Usually I have **20 images** in a page with around **15 ads** *(I can't remove amount of images or ads)*

Images are all optimized. I use `Lazy load` on images and `defer=true`, `asynchronous` on the ads.

Because of the ads, Images `Lazy Load` waits until page is **loaded** before start showing the images.

Is it any way I can make the content load **first** and ads later? Or any solution so `Lazy load` doesn't wait for all ads to load before it show the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lazy load` can't know if ads have been loaded, making ads `defer=true` will give some helps but you might lose some ad impressions since ads are loaded `after`. Best way is to optimize the image and remove `lazy load` on pages with many ads and images in same page.